# How to manipulate a list of dictionaries in Ansible?

Tags: ansible, yaml, jinja2

There is a list of dictionaries as shown below:

```
"test_list_of_dicts": [
{
  "inner_dict":[
    {"f1":"a","f2":"b"},
    {"f1":"c","f2":"d"}
  ],
  "id":"id1"
},
{
  "inner_dict":[
    {"f1":"e","f2":"f"},
    {"f1":"g","f2":"h"}
  ],
  "id":"id2"
}
]
```

I need to modify above structure and get a new list of dicts like below:

```
"new_list_of_dicts": [
    {"f1":"a","f2":"b","id":"id1"},
    {"f1":"c","f2":"d","id":"id1"},
    {"f1":"e","f2":"f","id":"id2"},
    {"f1":"g","f2":"h","id":"id2"}
]
```

I couldn't find a way to achieve this in Ansible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For example

```yaml
    - set_fact:
        new_list_of_dicts: "{{ new_list_of_dicts|d([]) + [item|combine] }}"
      with_subelements:
        - "{{ test_list_of_dicts }}"
        - inner_dict
```

gives

```yaml
  new_list_of_dicts:
    [
        {
            "f1": "a",
            "f2": "b",
            "id": "id1"
        },
        {
            "f1": "c",
            "f2": "d",
            "id": "id1"
        },
        {
            "f1": "e",
            "f2": "f",
            "id": "id2"
        },
        {
            "f1": "g",
            "f2": "h",
            "id": "id2"
        }
    ]
```

See [with_subelements](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_loops.html#with-subelements) and [subelements](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/builtin/subelements_lookup.html#ansible-builtin-subelements-traverse-nested-key-from-a-list-of-dictionaries).

Comment: The suggestion worked and produced the expected result. Thank you.

Comment: Consider @Zeitounator's one-liner. You can use it also outside tasks and make the code cleaner if you want to.

Answer (score 2):

Basically the same example as in @vladimir's answer but without the need for a loop:

```yaml
- name: manipulate dict
  hosts: localhost
  gather_facts: false

  vars:
    # Your var definition on a single line for legibility
    test_list_of_dicts: [{"inner_dict":[{"f1":"a","f2":"b"},{"f1":"c","f2":"d"}],"id":"id1"},{"inner_dict":[{"f1":"e","f2":"f"},{"f1":"g","f2":"h"}],"id":"id2"}]

    new_list_of_dicts: "{{ lookup('subelements', test_list_of_dicts, 'inner_dict')
      | map('combine') | list }}"

  tasks:
    - name: Show result
      debug:
        var: new_list_of_dicts
```

Which give as well:

```
PLAY [manipulate dict] *****************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************

TASK [show result] *********************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
ok: [localhost] => {
    "new_list_of_dicts": [
        {
            "f1": "a",
            "f2": "b",
            "id": "id1"
        },
        {
            "f1": "c",
            "f2": "d",
            "id": "id1"
        },
        {
            "f1": "e",
            "f2": "f",
            "id": "id2"
        },
        {
            "f1": "g",
            "f2": "h",
            "id": "id2"
        }
    ]
}

PLAY RECAP *****************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
localhost                  : ok=1    changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=0    skipped=0    rescued=0    ignored=0
```

Comment: i think var name in tasks should be "new_list_of_dicts". also i got an error "<generator object do_map at 0x7fa92d9d0af0>" when i used this suggestion. it might be due to a syntax problem, i don't know. anyway, thank you for an alternative suggestion.

Comment: @Jai: you are using ansible 2.9 or earlier. I fixed the example so it works with your version too (i.e. added the `list` filter after `map`). Fixed the typo in the debug as well, the output was genererated with a correct version. Sorry for that last one.